# How do I assign a return statement to a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, return, var

```js
var robotLeaves = "The robot has left to get milk!"
var byeRobot = return robotLeaves;
```

I'm trying to display what's assigned to the robotLeaves variable by using a return statement. Additionally, I'm trying to assign that return statement to a variable so I can reuse it.

Which websites || resources should I check out in order to find the solution for how to accomplish this?

edit:
Here's the full code I'm experimenting with:

```js
function getMilk() {
  var shop = 10;
  var robotLeaves = "The robot has left to get milk!"
  var robotReturns = "The robot has come back with 1 bottle of milk!"
  var byeRobot = return robotLeaves;

  byeRobot;
  if(byeRobot) {
    --shop;
    return robotReturns;
    return shop;
  };
}
getMilk();
```

2nd edit:
It turns out I was using the return statement incorrectly! Thank you to all who posted!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by return here, as the variable is already defined. `return` is used for functions

Comment: return works only in functions. where is your surrounding function?

Comment: You need to use a function for return statements

Comment: What do you mean "reuse"? How do you want to reuse it?

Comment: Why not simply `var byeRobot = robotLeaves` ? Also why not use `robotLeaves` directly?

Comment: `The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Can you complete your code ?

Comment: @oneAndZeros, nice name, anyhow, I think you are trying to assign that variable to be used later I get it in a way even your question is not very Clear, but let me know here are you trying to store the value to recall it later in another page or at the same page, that if i got you correctly else, explain more instead of keeping us trying to guess everyone here seems to be glad to help you.. :)

Comment: @SterlingArcher Ah. That explains it. I was using it wrong it seems.

Comment: @NinaScholz That explains why it wasn't working. I edited my question to include the entire program I'm experimenting with.

Comment: @iliasse Ah I see. Thank you for the explanation. It seems I was using it incorrectly.

Comment: @crupest To answer that I'll explain the desired outcome of the program. What I aim to achieve is when the program runs, it will print to the console that a robot has gone to get milk and a shop (which has a starting amount of 10 milks) will have its count reduced by 1. Then the console will print a simple direction to the user stating "Type "more" to get more milk or type "done" to end program." If the user types "more" then the text will once again display that the robot has returned with milk and the shop's count will again reduce by 1, and so on and so forth.

Comment: @crupest This will continue until the user ends the program by typing "end" when given the prompt or until it recognizes the shop's count has reached 0.

Comment: @JeremyThille My aim for using return byeRobot was twofold: to display what's assigned to robotLeaves to the console, and to try to use byeRobot directly as my if condition - which unfortunately gave me an error the same way using robotLeaves did.

Comment: @MoshFeu That explains it. Thank you for providing the link as well.

Comment: @Genosite Yes, I edited the code to show the full program I have so far.

Comment: @Kai Yes, thank you for the help! Hopefully my comments here have been able to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense but what you're trying to do is pretty weird. `return` isn't like a function or a variable that gives you a value, it **only takes** values. You put it in a function, and whatever you return is what you get when you use the function later on. It's always the last thing a function does, when it returns, it stops executing. So `return` doesn't display anything, but you can pass whatever value you return to a function that DOES.

```js
function getRobotState() {
  return "The robot has left to get milk!";
}

var robotLeaves = getRobotState();//Run the function, retrieve whatever it returns, put it in a variable so you can reuse it.
//Display value
console.log(robotLeaves)
//You can use robotLeaves as many times as you want from here downwards.
postOnTwitter("Where is the robot? " + robotLeaves)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to do something like this?

```
var shop = 10;

function getMilk() {
  var robotLeaves = "The robot has left to get milk!"
  var robotReturns = "The robot has come back with 1 bottle of milk!"

  --shop;
  console.log(robotReturns);
  console.log(shop);
}

getMilk();
```